# A measure on a product space from well-behaved projections

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question.** Let $X$ be a set equipped with a $σ$-algebra of subsets $Σ$, and let $\mu$ be a bounded, finitely additive function to $[0,\infty)$ from the product algebra $Σ ⊗ Σ$ on $X × X$. Suppose that for each $E, F ∈ Σ$, both $\mu(E × -)$ and $\mu(- × F)$ are countably additive measures on $X$. Does it follow that $\mu$ is countably additive?

**First attempt at a proof.** It suffices to prove this case:

> For $E, F, E_1, E_2, …, F_1, F_2, … ∈ Σ$, if the $E_n × F_n$ are pairwise disjoint and $E × F = ⋃_n E_n × F_n$, then $$\mu(E × F) = \sum_n \mu(E_n × F_n)$$

Let $\nu = \mu(- × F)$ and let $\nu_n = \mu(- × F_n)$. For each $x ∈ E$, the sets $F_n$ such that $x ∈ E_n$ partition $F$, so since each $\mu(A × -)$ is countably additive, we have
$$
\nu = \sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) \, \nu_n
$$
It is tempting to "differentiate" this equation, and write:
$$
\mathrm{d}\nu = \sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) \, \mathrm{d}\nu_n
$$
and thus
$$
\int_{x ∈ E} 1 \; \mathrm{d}\nu = \sum_n \int_{x ∈ E} 1_{E_n}(x) \; \mathrm{d}\nu_n
$$
The left-hand side is equal to $\nu(E) = \mu(E × F)$, and the right-hand side is equal to $\sum_n \nu_n(E_n) = \sum_n \mu(E_n × F_n)$, so we'd be done. But I don't know whether that "differentiation" idea can be made rigorous, or even makes any sense.

**Second attempt.** As in the first attempt, for any $A ∈ Σ$ and any $x ∈ X$,
$$
\nu(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu_n(A) \, 1_{E_n}(x)
$$
So if $A_1, …, A_K$ is a finite partition of $E$, and we choose some $x_k ∈ A_k$ for each $k ≤ K$, then
$$
\nu(E) = \sum_k \nu(A_k) = \sum_k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu_n(A_k) \, 1_{E_n}(x_k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_k  \nu_n(A_k) \, 1_{E_n}(x_k)
$$
Meanwhile, for any $N$, we can let $A_1, …, A_K$ be the atoms of the finite Boolean algebra of sets generated by $E_1, …, E_N$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \nu_n(E_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_k \nu_n(A_k) \, 1_{E_n}(x_k)
$$
It's tempting to conclude that this converges to $\nu(E)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, which would suffice. But I don't think that works, because the partition $A_1, …, A_K$ is chosen in a way that depends on $N$, while the formula for $\nu(E)$ used a fixed partition.

Answer (score 1):

The differentiation idea was on the right track.

Each of the measures $\nu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, so each of them has a Radon-Nikodym derivative $f_n$ such that, for any $A ∈ Σ$,
$$
\nu_n(A) = \int_A f \, \mathrm{d}\nu
$$
Furthermore, for any $x ∈ E$, by countable additivity we have
$$
\int_A 1 \, \mathrm{d}\nu = \nu(A) = \sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) \nu_n(A) = \sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) \int_{A} f_n \, \mathrm{d}\nu = \int_{A} \sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) f_n \, \mathrm{d}\nu
$$
It follows that (for arbitrary fixed $x ∈ E$) $\sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) f_n = 1$ $\nu$-almost everywhere. So for $\nu$-almost all $x ∈ E$, $\sum_n 1_{E_n}(x) f_n(x) = 1$.

Thus
$$
\sum_n \nu_n(E_n) = \sum_n \int_{E_n} f_n \, \mathrm{d}\nu = \sum_n \int_E 1_{E_n} f_n \, \mathrm{d}\nu = \int_E \sum_n 1_{E_n} f_n \, \mathrm{d}\nu
= \int_E 1 \, \mathrm{d}\nu = \nu(E)
$$